# unable to build project in visual studio 11

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've install windows 8 consumer preview and Visual studio 11 developer preview.
After I'm creating a new windows project and attempting to build VS says that it needs .net framework 4.5 while .net framework 4.5 is already installed!

[image]

Comment: Try changing the target for the build to another version and see what happens, then maybe change it back and try again.

Comment: it works when i change target from .net framework 4.5 client to .net framework 4.5. but i have another issue i cant not add reference. it throws exception "method not found" when I click add reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview means this error message is expected.

You are required to switch to Visual Studio 11 Beta,

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us